# Visual studio not displaying git branches properly

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm trying to wrap my head around using git with Visual Studio. I have code on bitbucket that i want to work on, i cloned the repository and everything was displayed fine in the solution explorer/team explorer views. Then i made a small change (added a folder with an empty class in it) and committed it and pushed it, which also worked (all the changes appeared on remote).

I closed Visual Studio and opened it later on to see that now the solution explorer does not display the changes (i.e. the new folder). This seems to be a somewhat common problem but none of the solutions i googled helped me. I tried switching branches back and forth, restarting my PC. I even deleted the branch from local and downloaded it again from remote, but the solution checker still wouldn't display the new folder for me, which i find really confusing. Any suggestions what's going wrong and how can i fix it?

EDIT: It seems that everything is downloaded to local but no correctly displayed in the solution manager, maybe something is wrong with the solution file? Still, i have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently Visual Studio did not modify the solution file, i don't know why. I manually added the path to the new folder and it works now, that was the only problem.